# why can't I put an array name on the left side of an equals sign

Tags: c, arrays, unix, pointers

Why can't we do this in c:

```
   char name[6];
   name = "Jason";
```

However, with pointers we can.

```
  char name; 
  char * pName = &name; 
  pName = "Jason";
```

What is the major difference between arrays and pointers ? I understand that the array is a fixed constant pointer, fair enough but I'm not quite sure about how this works if the name of an array is a pointer(pointer constant) which points to the first element in the array why can't I change the content of the elements of that array with an equal sign? I  answered my question by saying it is a  pointer constant but I don't grasp this concept!

Comment: If you think about what a pointer is, then you ought to realize that `pName = "Jason";` isn't copying anything. You're just making `pName` point at a string, which is _read-only_ anyway

Answer (score 2):

Because when you write `"a constant string"`, the compiler allocates this string in the compiled code and if you do `c = "a string"` where `c` is a pointer, `c` will now point to that particular location.

The position of an array instead is fixed (you cannot say "now point to something else"), so you should copy the string with `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(name, "Jason");
```

In this way the compiler will allocate `"Jason"` in the compiled code, but at execution time its content will be copied in the memory area dedicated to `name`.

Comment: From this logic I understand that the compiler executes each statement in a certain address in the RAM and because the array is a pointer constant: means the position cannot be changed that's why I can't use the equals sign in here as it will change the fixed address.

Answer (score 1):

C never copies bare strings (the actual character data) around as a result of evaluating the `=` assignment operator. This is because such a thing is not considered "a value" in C. You can embed an array into a struct to make it a value, as pointed out in a comment.

Your first example would only make sense if it did, but it doesn't. The second example just assigns a pointer value, which is fine. But you cannot re-assign the address of an array (`name` is a constant pointer in the first example) so there's no way to make it work.

Also, remember that there are more arrays than character arrays, it would be weird to have that much special behavior overloaded on the `=` operator for character arrays, in my opinion.

Comment: Actually, if you have a struct with a member of type _array-of-char_, and you use the assignment operator with two values of such type... the string will be copied. So you have that special behavior for structs anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, an array name is effectively a constant pointer to the array.

Since a constant object cannot be modified during execution, specifying an array as a **lvalue** i.e. to the left of an assignment operator is invalid.

To use your example, the following is the equivalent of trying to assigning something to a array name :

```
char name; 
const char *pName = &name; 
pName = "Jason";    //error!!
```

Checkout **[`memcpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)**, **[`strcpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/strcpy.html)** to modify contents of an arrays. Take care to ensure that the arrays being written-to aren't constant (or statically allocated).